# Can AutoFixture be used to generate multiple test cases?

Tags: xunit.net, autofixture, automoq

I've started to experiment with AutoFixture. In my research I found that there is this `InlineAutoDataAttribute` which one could used to generate multiple test cases with varying input arguments (given some requirements). However, `InlineAttribute` and similarly `InlineAutoDataAttribute` can only work with compile `const` data. So I went looking for something like `MemberAutoDataAttribute`, as `MemberDataAttribute` would allow me to feed in a collection of non-'compile time const' objects, like a collection of `Exception` instances. Sadly, this attribute doesn't exist.

Is there some way how I could reuse a test making use of AutoFixture such that it can generate multiple test cases? Could this be achieved with some `ICustomization` implementation?

Below is an example of the situation I'm describing. Note that `MyCustomAutoDataAttribute` is just an basic inherited object of `AutoDataAttribute` that causes the `AutoMoqCustomization` to be configured for the fixture.

```
[Theory, MyCustomAutoDataAttribute]
public void FooBar(Exception exception, [Frozen] ISomeInterface)
{
    ...
    ISomeInterface.Setup(i => i.SomeMethod()).Throws(exception);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workable solution to my problem. It feels like a workaround through, but it got the job done for me.

```
[Theory]
[MyCustomInlineAutoData(typeof(CustomException1))]
[MyCustomInlineAutoData(typeof(CustomException2))]
public void FooBar(Type exceptionType, [Frozen] Mock<ISomeInterface> interface, [Frozen] IFixture fixture)
{
    var exception = (Exception) new SpecimenContext(fixture).Resolve(exceptionType)
    interface.Setup(i => i.SomeMethod()).Throws(exception);
}
```

with the following definition for the attribute:

```
public class MyCustomInlineAutoData : InlineAutoDataAttribute
{
    public MyCustomInlineAutoData(params object[] values) : base(new MyCustomAutoDataAttribute(), values)
    {

    }
}
```